# How to add a stylesheet conditionally based on a component in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I have a component with a `styleUrls`.

This component is not shown by default because I have a `*ngIf`.

If true, the component is displayed in the page with the CSS. The CSS is automatically added to the document `<head>`.

If false, the component is not displayed anymore, but its CSS is still in the page, inside the `<head>`.

How can I remove this CSS from `<head></head>` when the component itself is not displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional stylesheet on your index.html by using `*ngIf='YOUR_COMPONENT_ROUTE_HERE === THIS_ROUTE'. Not sure if the stylesheet will load.`

You can set conditional CSS classes like this:

```
<element NgStyle={condition? true: false} > </element>
```

For example:

```
<element NgStyle={isNew ? 'new' : 'default' } > </element>
```

Let me know if you have any further questions..

Comment: I want to add some CSS outside my component, like "body" or "html", which are outside the root component.

Comment: I think there might be a more elegant solution to what you're asking here.. I just need more information to work with what you're really trying to accomplish

Comment: Yeah! I have a component named Popup, inside my root component. The CSS of the Popup component, is not here at the loading page, because the component is not displayed. Once the popup component is displayed, the CSS too. But when the popup is not displayed anymore, the CSS still remains. In the CSS, I have so properties which changes the CSS of <body> (outside the root component AND outside the popup component) and #header (inside the root component but outside the Popup component). How can I do that without access the DOM by get element by id ... ? Thanks

Comment: I would need to see a PLUNKR or your project structure. Your architecture could be misaligned, or your approach is against best practices and might cause you more bottlenecks like this in the future.